# Degree of a multivariate polynomial over a finite field with many roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, finite-fields, multivariate-polynomial

**Question**

Let $q$ be a prime power, $k\in\{1,\ldots,q-1\}$ and $f$ be a multivariate polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ having $q^n - k$ roots.

Show that $\deg(f) \geq (q-1)n - k + 1$.

(The inequality has been updated due to a comment of Jyrki Lahtonen. There has been the weaker inequality $\deg(f) \geq (q-1)n - k$ before.)

**Motivation**

For all $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$, we have $a^q = a$. This shows that we can replace $x_i^q$ in f by $x_i$ without changing the set of roots, so that we may assume that the degree in every single variables is at most $q-1$. The total degree $\deg(f)$ is then at most $(q-1)n$. It is not hard show that every function $\mathbb{F}_q^n \to \mathbb{F}_q$ can be represented by a unique polynomial with these properties (total degree at most $(q-1)m$; degree in every single variable at most $q-1$).

So the question asks for polynomials whose number of roots is close to the maximum $q^n$. The aim is to show that the degree has to be at least equally close to the maximum (in the above sense) total degree $(q-1)m$.

Comment: The Schwartz-Zippel lemma (Lemma 1.2 in [Terence Tao, *Algebraic combinatorial geometry: the polynomial method in arithmetic combinatorics, incidence combinatorics, and number theory*, arXiv:1310.6482v5](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6482v5)) says that $q^n - k \leq \deg\left(f\right) \cdot q^{n-1}$. Does this yield your inequality?

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you. resolving your inequality for deg(f) I get $\deg(f) \geq q - \frac{k}{q^{n-1}} > q$, which in general is weaker than what I want, right?

Comment: I don't have time to check which inequality is weaker now; but I would be surprised if one can do better than Schwartz-Zippel without extra assumptions.

Comment: @darijgrinberg the extra assumption is that almost all evaluation points are roots.

Comment: Ah! That sounds more plausible.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I changed the title to give more emphasis to this assumption

Comment: I think you are "off by one". $\deg f\ge n(q-1)-(k-1)$ which is one higher than what you asked for. So slightly stronger.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's true. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the $\Bbb{F}_q$-span of monomials $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{m_i}$ with $0\le m_i\le q-1$ for all $i$. The dimension of the space $V$ is thus $q^n$ which is equal to the number of points in $S=\Bbb{F}_q^n$. By Lagrange interpolation any function $f:S\to\Bbb{F}_q$ can be described by evaluating a polynomial $\phi_f$. Without loss of generality (see the question) we can assume that $\phi_f\in V$. The conclusion is that $\phi_f\in V$ is *uniquely* determined by $f$. Therefore we can forget about the distinction between $f$ and $\phi_f$, when we restrict ourselves to $V$. However, we must
be careful in that $V$ is not closed under multiplication. Rather, $V$ gives as set of representatives of all the cosets of the quotient ring
$$
R_n=\Bbb{F}_q[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/\langle x_1^q-x_1,\ldots,x_n^q-x_n\rangle.
$$

I think the following argument shows that whenever there are exactly $k>0$ points, $P_1,\ldots,P_k \in S$ such $f(P_i)\neq0$ for all $i=1,2,\dots,k$, then
$$\deg f\ge (q-1)n-k+1.$$
That is, one higher than required.

We proceed and prove the claim by induction on $k$. The starting point $k=1$ is seen as follows. Let $P_1=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ be the unique point where $f$ does not vanish.
The polynomial
$$
f_{P_1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i^q-x_i}{x_i-a_i}
$$
is one such, for the $i$th factor vanishes whenever $x_i\in \Bbb{F}_q, x_i\neq a_i$. Observe that $f_{P_1}$ is of degree $q-1$ in all the variables, so it has degree $(q-1)n$ and belongs to $V$. By the uniqueness result described above we thus have $f=\lambda f_{P_1}$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$. This proves the base case $k=1$.

Assume that for some $k>1$ we have a polynomial $f\in V$ of degree $<(q-1)n-(k-1)$
that vanishes at all the points of $S$ except at $P_1,P_2,\ldots, P_k$. Consider the
collection of maximal degree terms in $f$. Because $\deg f<n(q-1)$ there exists a monomial $\prod_i x_i^{m_i}$ of degree $\deg f$ with a non-zero coefficient in $f$ such that some exponent,
say $m_{i_0}<q-1$. Let $P_k=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. Consider the polynomial
$\tilde f:= (x_{i_0}-a_{i_0}) f$. It vanishes whenever $f$ vanishes, and also at the point $P_k$, so $\tilde{f}$ non-vanishes at at most $k-1$ points of $S$. By the induction hypothesis we have
$$
\deg\tilde{f}\ge n(q-1)-((k-1)-1)=n(q-1)-(k-1)+1.
$$
But, by the choice of $i_0$, we also have $\deg\tilde{f}=\deg f +1$. Therefore
$$\deg f\ge n(q-1)-(k-1)$$
proving the inductive step.

---

I don't see the need for the assumption $k<q$. Of course, the lower bound on the degree becomes trivial rather quickly at around $k=n(q-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for very clear solution! So the basic idea is pretty simple: Add further roots to f in the simplest possible way (linear factor) and apply induction. But of course, the details are a bit tricky and need to be worked out, as you did.