# Find a multivariate polynomial over finite field with given zeros (or number of zeros) with an upper bound on its degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry, roots, finite-fields, multivariate-polynomial

This is a follow-up on: [Find a multivariate polynomial over finite field with given zeros (or number of zeros)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769414/find-a-multivariate-polynomial-over-finite-field-with-given-zeros-or-number-of).

I am trying to find a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m]/(x_i^q-x_i)$ such that $f-1=0$ has precisely a given number of roots.

As answered by @qiaochu-yuan, this is always possible, and one can find the appropriate polynomial by solving linearly for the coefficients.

My question now is, when (and how) can one find such a polynomial $f$ such that $deg(f) \leq d_0$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728636/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The relevant tricks and bounds really depend on the desired number of zeros and the range of $d_0$. I would expect that if you prescribe a lot of zeros or a lot of non-zeros, then the degree will necessarily be close to the maximum of $m(q-1)$. At the other end of very low degree polynomials we have results like [Chevalley-Warning](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChevalleysTheorem.html) telling that the number of zeros must be a multiple of $q$.